# Outputting a calculation

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I validated this script on the w3 validator and it validated with no errors but when I try to calculate something within the cart there's no output.I was just wondering what the problem was.

```
 <script type=text/javascript>
    function shoppingcart()
        {
        var TaxRate=0.10;
        var Tax=0;
        var Subtotal=0;
        var Total=0;

        var quantity=document.getElementById("quantity").value;
        var price=document.getElementById("Choice").value;

        SubTotal=Quantity*Price;
        tax=SubTotal*Taxrate;
        total=SubTotal+tax;

        tax=tax.toFixed(2);
        SubTotal=SubTotal.toFixed(2);
        total=total.toFixed(2);
                <!--data back to form-->
        document.getElementById('subtotal').innerHTML="Subtotal="+subTotal;
        document.getElementById('totalTax').innerHTML="Totaltax="+tax+"(@10)";
        document.getElementById('total'). innerHTML="Total=" +total;

        alert("CheckTotal")
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
     <script type=text/javascript></script>

    <form OnSubmit="shoppingcart()">
    <h1>Shopping cart</h1>
    Choose option
    <select>

        <option value="">Select </option>
        <option value="$20">"spin classes $20</option>
        <option value="$40"> "swimming lessons $40</option>
        <option value="$10"> Boxersize $10</option>
        <option value="$5"> protein shake $5</option>
    </select>

    <label for="session">Session:</label>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" size="1" id="session">
    <br>
    <hr>
    <div id="Subtotal">Subtotal:</div>
    <div id="Tax">Tax:</div>
    <div id="Total">Total:</div>
    <hr>
    <input type="submit" value="calculate"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Data back to form was just a comment

Comment: ThanKs i shall check to what the problem is now

Comment: You're trying to get the elements with ID quantity and Choice, and there aren't such elements in your HTML.

Comment: Looking at the console in your browser (F12 in Chrome) should have shown you the problem.

Comment: id is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

The elements you were trying to write to doesn't appear in the HTML part of your code

some of them doesn't exist at all and some have wrong casing

This is my guess for what you meant:

`document.getElementById('subtotal')` should be  `document.getElementById('Subtotal')` (with a capital S) to match the name of the element

`document.getElementById('totalTax')` should be `document.getElementById('Tax')`

and

`document.getElementById('total')` should be `document.getElementById('Total')`

Comment: thanks for your time it is very helpful. These small errors get me all of the time

Answer (score 0):

Variable names are case sensitive. You define `quantity` , `price` , `TaxRate` , `Subtotal` ...
but use `Quantity` , `Price` , `Taxrate` , `SubTotal`.

Answer (score 0):

lots of error in your program, remenber javascript is casesenstive;
your taking element name in place of id `document.getElementById("quantity").value;` here quantity is **name** not **id**
your errors are mostly in variable names
**quantity  as Quantity , price as Price , TaxRate  as Taxrate, Subtotal as SubTotal, Quantity as quantity**
*check below code i fix all errors*

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    function shoppingcart(){
        var TaxRate=0.10;
        var Tax=0;
        var Subtotal=0;
        var Total=0;

        var quantity=Number(document.getElementById("session").value);
        var price=Number(document.getElementById("Choice").value);

        Subtotal=quantity*price;

        tax=Subtotal*TaxRate;

        total=Subtotal+tax;

        Tax=Tax.toFixed(2);

        Subtotal=Subtotal.toFixed(2);

        Total=Total.toFixed(2);
                <!--data back to form-->
        document.getElementById('Subtotal').innerHTML="Subtotal="+Subtotal;
        document.getElementById('Tax').innerHTML="Totaltax="+tax+"(@10)";
        document.getElementById('Total'). innerHTML="Total=" +total;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
     <script type=text/javascript></script>
    <form >
    <h1>Shopping cart</h1>
    Choose option
    <select id="Choice">
        <option value="">Select </option>
        <option value="20">"spin classes $20</option>
        <option value="40"> "swimming lessons $40</option>
        <option value="10"> Boxersize $10</option>
        <option value="5"> protein shake $5</option>
    </select>

    <label for="session">Session:</label>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" size="1" id="session">

    <br>
    <hr>
    <div id="Subtotal">Subtotal:</div>
    <div id="Tax">Tax:</div>
    <div id="Total">Total:</div>
    <hr>

    <input type="button" onClick="shoppingcart()" value="calculate"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I am noticing in the code. Any of them could be a problem.

1) var quantity=document.getElementById("quantity").value;

I don't see an element with the id quantity. That's the name, not the id. The id of the input name quantity is session.

2) I don't see an element id named "choice". Maybe you forgot to include that. Remember getElementById is looking at values by "id" not "name". You are going to need to make sure that you are accessing the right "id"s.

as someone already mentioned

```
document.getElementById('subtotal').innerHTML="Subtotal="+subTotal;
document.getElementById('totalTax').innerHTML="Totaltax="+tax+"(@10)";
document.getElementById('total'). innerHTML="Total=" +total;
```

someone already mentioned there are problems here. The id for subtotal is actually Subtotal. Everything is case sensitive. I don't see an id for totaltax. I see one for Tax and I also don't see an id for total, but for Total (note the uppercase).

Your problem seems to lie in mismatched ids.